# Get price value from span tag and append it inside a div after multiplying with a number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html on the checkout page of my website

```html
<tr class="order-total">
    <th>Total</th>
    <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>24,500.00</span></strong> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have to multiply this price(24,500) with 0.0198 and show it in side a div which is on the same page in another section. This is what I have tried:

```js
jQuery('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').load(function () {
  var totprice = jQuery('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').val();
  var leaseprice = totprice * 0.0198;
  jQuery(".leaseprice_container").append(leaseprice);    
});
```

The section where I am trying to show the leaseprice has this html:

```html
<div class="leaseprice_container">
    <p><strong>Prices are in USD.</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `val()` is only used to get value from form control elements. You are also showing an extra `</span>` in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ge the value using [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) and not [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/), which is for input elements, you can trim it and replace the `$` sign and the comma with an empty character in order to have a correct float number format in order to make `parseFloat()` to work. Then you can place the result in the section you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totprice = parseFloat($(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount")
                               .text()
                               .trim()
                               .replace('$','')
                               .replace(',',''));
    var leaseprice = totprice * 0.0198;
    $(".leaseprice_container strong").text(leaseprice);
});
```

Comment: Just tried it. Thanks it worked. But I want to keep this text: Prices are in USD.
and I have to add one more word at the beginning of this line. Like this: 

"LEASE TOTAL: TOTAL PRICE x 0.0198 = 1714.78"

Comment: @Rahul I think you want to look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63579551/295783)

Answer (score 1):

There is no .load on an html element. One would use

`$("selector").load("url",function() {...})`

to load data from the backend

A span does not have .val()

Try this

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

const totprice = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace(/(\$|,)/g, "");

const leaseprice = totprice * 0.0198;

console.log(totprice,leaseprice)

$(".leaseprice_container p strong").prepend(formatter.format(leaseprice)+" ")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="order-total">
  <th>Total</th>
  <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>24,500.00</span></strong>
  </td>
</tr>
<div class="leaseprice_container">
  <p><strong>Prices are in USD.</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use the `jQuery()` function which is shorthand for `document.load`.
- You need to get the `text()` of the span because only `inputs` have values.
- You need to remove everythign that isn't a number from the text so Javascript can use it as a number. (`.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')`)

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var totprice = jQuery('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');;
  var leaseprice = totprice * 0.0198;
  jQuery(".leaseprice_container").append(leaseprice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class="order-total">
  <th>Total</th>
  <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>24,500.00</span></strong>
  </td>
</tr>

<div class="leaseprice_container">
  <p><strong>Prices are in USD.</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working when I am running the code here. But when I run it in the console it isn't running and I am not intending the replace the "Prices are in USD" text also.

Comment: ok well you have to tell us why it isn't working. we're not mind readers. if you can't reproduce the issue then all we can do is guess. what does the console say?

Comment: It shows no error. That's the problem. I tried Vasilis solutions and it is running but it is replacing the entire text in the strong tag which I have to keep. This price and a word has to be appended in below/above that strong tag.

Comment: i see no reason why his would work and mine wouldn't, they both do the exact same thing in different ways. but if his works for you can just change the last line in his answer to use `.append(leaseprice);` instead of `.text(leaseprice);` and it will add to it instead of erase it.

Answer (score 1):

I used a regex to remove all not number characters, then do all the calculation in integer, and then returning to the real decimal base, in order to avoid rounding errors.

```js
var price = Number.parseInt($('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[\D]/g, ''));
var leaseprice = price * 198 / 1000000;
$(".leaseprice_container .price").text(leaseprice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="order-total">
    <th>Total</th>
    <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>24,500.00</span></strong> 
    </td>
</tr>

<div class="leaseprice_container">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span><span class="price"></span>
    <p><strong>Prices are in USD.</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It replaces the text which I was intending to keep(Prices are in USD). Can we append it with the modified price?

Comment: Read better the solution, you have to add a span element to target the insertion and avoid the replacement